# Can't bind to 'hero' since it isn't a known property of 'app-hero-detail'

Tags: angular

I'm stuck [on the third step of the Angular tour of heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3), last time I checked, in Angular 2 and 4, this solution worked. What has changed since then?

Here's the screenshot of the error I'm getting in the browser console.

[image]

And here's a [link to my repo on Github.](https://github.com/psa007/angular-tour-of-heroes)

In `HeroDetailComponent`, I've got this.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

`hero-detail.component.html`

```
<div *ngIf="hero">
  <h2>{{ hero.name | uppercase }} Details</h2>
  <div><span>id: </span>{{ hero.id }}</div>
  <div>
    <label
      >name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

In `heroes.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

in the template file -

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li
    *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)"
  >
    <span class="badge">{{ hero.id }}</span> {{ hero.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
<app-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></app-hero-detail>
```

How can I get to the next step?

Comment: Please post your code here as links may die in the future.

Comment: Include your template code from the ts file. And don't expect people to go and look into your source to find the write thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have an `@Input() hero` in `app-hero-detail` component.
The error is thrown when you assign a property that is not defined in the component.

There could also be the case that  `app-hero-detail` is not a part of the `declarations` array property of the `@NgModule`

Update: 
https://stackblitz.com/github/psa007/angular-tour-of-heroes

You are bootstrapping the wrong AppModule !
Inside the `main.ts` file you are loading another AppModule and not the app.module.ts

Comment: Thanks @Dhananjai I have all of that present in my code. Here - https://github.com/psa007/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/2e4848f4f73c0509f4c4f0065afe09e3eba98d79/src/app/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.ts#L10

and here - https://github.com/psa007/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/2e4848f4f73c0509f4c4f0065afe09e3eba98d79/src/app/app.module.ts#L11

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
```

try to use

```
<input [value]="hero?.name" placeholder="name" />
```

## Update -

Also you need to add your details componenet in the app.module file like below -

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeroesComponent, HeroDetailComponent],   <-- changes here
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Yes I have that in my repo bro, updated my question with more code snippet check here - https://github.com/psa007/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/2e4848f4f73c0509f4c4f0065afe09e3eba98d79/src/app/app.module.ts#L11

Comment: https://github.com/psa007/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/2e4848f4f73c0509f4c4f0065afe09e3eba98d79/src/app/AppModule.ts I am checking here

Answer (score 2):

I donno if this helps but try importing `HeroDetailComponent` in your `declarations` array of `hero.component.spec.ts`

You have to do this to avoid failing tests

Answer (score 2):

File:
src/app/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.ts

Details:
1. Add the line which is given as "Add this line" below:
2. if this didn't solve, you are saving too fast, or your computer is slow, so add a new blank line (press Enter) and save it once again so that ng-serve will take it correctly.
3. if above two didn't solve, then check all the files given in code review at: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3#final-code-review

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() hero: Hero; /// <----------------------------- *** add this line (and save file)

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: This line is already added and make no difference.

Comment: Do you suggest I delete this answer? Let me know, I will.

Comment: No! Your answer is not exactly wrong. The error message deals precisely with the line you pointed to.

The question here is just that it may happen that this message keeps showing up even after adding this line due to an error in "ng serve".

Comment: Your answer is useful for those who follow the whole discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Appmodule file one is app.module.ts and another one AppModule and your main.ts is pointing to AppModule In that you have not included heroDetailsComponent

**angular-tour-of-heroes/src/app/AppModule.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeroesComponent, HeroDetailComponent ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost 2 years later and I am at Angular 11 and I had exactly the same problem following the tutorial. For an instant I thought it was a bug or some step missing from the tutorial, but in fact in my case it was something much more deceptive and it took me hours to solve.

It turns out that when we followed the tutorial at first we didn't define this line:

@Input () hero: Hero;

This part of the code is added in the next steps. The error message is because this line is currently missing!

But if we make a syntax error before we add that, it may be that "ng serve" stops working properly and therefore stops "refreshing" part of the files correctly.

This causes it to display the same old error message, although the code necessary for it to disappear is added.

So even if in the following steps the line is added, the same message keeps showing up because "ng serve" is not refreshing properly.

To fix it, just drop the "ng serve" on the console with "CTRL + C" and then type "ng serve" to start it again and everything starts to work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Add instruction `hero: Hero` to heroesComponent.ts

Answer (score 0):

in hero-detail.component.ts

```
@Input() hero?: Hero;
```